# how to get button using id and call its click event - Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have a button that call a function on ng-click , my issue is : how can i get this button using the id and call the click event on my Angular run function, this is my code :

```
<button ng-click="myfunction()" id="myButton">Click !!</button>


app.run(['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
// by default i want to click my button when the app is loaded
}]);
```

Note: i have a problem with "myfunction()" , this why i want to call it indirectly.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are wanting won't work.Generally your html won;t exist when app is loaded and `run()` block executes if you are using routing or directive templates and the dom hasn't been compiled either and neither has controller been run.  Why not fix `myfunction()` here?

Comment: IMHO, simulating user interaction to trigger a function automatically is a bad idea. This often leads into subsequent problems. If you could elaborate more, what keeps you from calling `myfunction()` directly, probably this might help us suggesting a cleaner alternative? Using the `ngInit` attribute, as @avim101 suggested, could be a solution - although it does not happen during app startup.

Comment: Hello guys , to explain you what is my problem, i'm using this tree-grid : http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html  , when the page is loaded all the elements in the grid are expanded, so if i want to collapse them , i should click the button, to fix my problem i'm trying  to call the collapse function without clicking on the button, do you have any suggestion to fix this issue? thank you in advance

Comment: All you need to do is set the expand-level property. It's part of the api already. No need for this button or function hack. This has beena  complete XY Problem...always include relevant details related to higher level problem

Comment: Hi @charlietfl , please , can you show me where and how to set the expand-level property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ng-init

```
<button ng-click="myfunction()" id="myButton" ng-init="myfunction()">Click !!</button>
```

but if you still want:

```
$timeout(function() { angular.element('#myButton').triggerHandler('click'); });
```

Comment: thank you @avim 101 for your suggestion, i solve my problem, using this snippet of code :                $timeout(function() {
    angular.element('#myButton').triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);

Comment: @ali glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

To execute a function when a controller is loaded simply invoke it in the controller.

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="myFunction()" id="myButton">Click !!</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    //Define function
    $scope.myFunction = function (event) {
        //Perform click function
    };

    //Invoke function when controller loaded
    $scope.myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Can also assign $scope.myFunction to a global variable so you can quickly run it from console if needed ...  `window.test =  $scope.myFunction`

Comment: thank you @georgeawing for the response, my problem is, i'm using this tree-grid : http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html  , when the page is loaded all the elements in the grid are expanded, so if i want to collapse them , i should click the button, to fix my problem i'm trying  to call the collapse function without clicking on the button, do you have any suggestion to fix this issue? thank you in advance